# Get a record from 2016 that doesn't exist in 2017 for a specific name in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

- Contests(NameID, Date)
- Competitors(ID, Name)
- Results(NameID, ID, result)

I am looking to extract the name of a contest in which *Player A* participated in 2016 and didn't attend in 2017 anymore. In 2016 the contest name is *ContestA 2016* and in 2017 *ContestA 2017* but there are also another competitions in which the player didn't participate

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

edit: thank you. both answers helped . much appreciated!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that "the same" contest does not have a unique id (ContestA 2016 and ContestA 2017)? If so, in order to even recognize "a conest" to be the same a substring has to be performed on the column. Is it same enough to extract the name by removing last 5 characters from the Contests.NameID?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly . The table contests don't have a defined unique id, i used just the name of the competition and yes it would be same by removing last 5 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something as following:

```
Select distinct LEFT(res.NameID, LEN(res.NameID)-5) as CompetitionName, res.ID as CompetitorName
From Results res
Join Contests con on con.NameID = res.NameID
Join Competitors com on com.ID = res.ID
Where
    con.date between '1.1.2016' and '31.12.2016' and 
    not exists
    (
        Select res2.NameID
        From Results res2 
        Join Contests con2 on con2.NameID = res2.NameID
        Where
            con2.date between '1.1.2017' and '31.12.2017' and 
            LEFT(res2.NameID, LEN(res2.NameID)-5) = LEFT(res.NameID, LEN(res.NameID)-5) and res2.ID = res.ID
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM (Results r 
INNER JOIN Competitors c ON r.ID = c.ID)
INNER JOIN Contests n ON r.NameID = n.NameID
WHERE Year(n.Date) = 2016 AND r.ID = <Player A ID>
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM (Results sub_r 
     INNER JOIN Competitors sub_c ON sub_r.ID = sub_c.ID)
     INNER JOIN Contests sub_n ON sub_r.NameID = sub_n.NameID
     WHERE Year(sub_n.Date) = 2017
     AND r.ID = sub_r.ID)
```